# Mysql enabling remote and local access

Tags: mysql

I just enabled remote access on my mysql server. 
I did this by going to the database 'mysql' , then the user table and changing the Host column to '%' of the appropriate user. After doing this I noticed that I can't access it locally i.e. when I'm logged into the server via the SHELL, I can't login.

Is it not possible to have both local and remote access ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a separate row in the `mysql.user` table with a `host` value of 'localhost', to enable local unix socket type connections.

A value of `'%'` in the `host` column is for the TCP protocol.

Details in the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

I have three rows for a user in the `mysql.user` table, with `host` values of `'localhost'` (for unix socket type connections), `'127.0.0.1'` for access via TCP from the local host, and `'%'` for TCP access from other hosts.

Note that MySQL identifies a user not just by the "username", but as the combination of "username" and "host".  These are considered distinct users, and each of them can have a different password and a different set of privileges.